# How can I mix similar code using loops (for/while) in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some code repeated, where only some numbers are changing.

```
df_h0 = df.copy()
df_h0['hour']='00:00'
df_h0['totalCount']=df.post_time_data.str.split('"00:00","postCount":"').str[1].str.split('","topic').str[0]
df_h0 = df_h0.fillna(0)

df_h1 = df.copy()
df_h1['hour']='01:00'
df_h1['totalCount']=df.post_time_data.str.split('"01:00","postCount":"').str[1].str.split('","topic').str[0]
df_h1 = df_h1.fillna(0)

df_h2 = df.copy()
df_h2['hour']='02:00'
df_h2['totalCount']=df.post_time_data.str.split('"02:00","postCount":"').str[1].str.split('","topic').str[0]
df_h2 = df_h2.fillna(0)
```

I want to simplify this code with a loop but I'm not sure how to start with that since I'm new in Python.

Comment: code with for/while will not simpler but longer and it may work slower because dataframe uses code in C/C++

Comment: As asked, this is not really a Pandas question, even though the code happens to use Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to show what the process looks like in general, so that you can figure these things out yourself in the future. However, it's not automatic - you will need to think about what you are doing every time, in order to write the best code you are capable of.

## Step 1: Grab a single representative block of the code you want to repeat, and identify the parts that change:

```
df_h0 = df.copy()
# ^^^ the variable name changes
df_h0['hour']='00:00'
#              ^^^^^ the hour string changes
df_h0['totalCount']=df.post_time_data.str.split('"00:00","postCount":"').str[1].str.split('","topic').str[0]
# the delimiter string changes                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
df_h0 = df_h0.fillna(0)
```

## Step 2: Understand that our output will be a *list* of values, instead of multiple separate variables with related names.

This will be much easier to work with going forward :)

## Step 3: Analyze the changes.

We have an hour string which varies, and a delimiter string which also varies; but the delimiter string always has the same general form, which is based upon the hour string. So if we have the hour string, we can create the delimiter string. There is really only one piece of varying information - the hour. We'll adjust the code to reflect that:

```
hour = '00:00' # give the variable information a name
delimiter = f'"{hour}","postCount":"' # compute the derived information
# and then use those values in the rest of the code
df_h0 = df.copy()
df_h0['hour'] = hour
df_h0['totalCount']=df.post_time_data.str.split(delimiter).str[1].str.split('","topic').str[0]
df_h0 = df_h0.fillna(0)
```

## Step 4: To make the overall code easier to understand, we put this block into its own *function*.

That lets us give a name to the process of making a single table. We use the input to the function to provide the varying information that we described in step 3. There is one thing that changes, so there will be one parameter to represent that. However, we also need to provide the data *context* that we're working with here - the `df` dataframe - so that the function has access to it. So we have two parameters in total.

```
def hourly_data(df, hour):
    # since 'hour' was provided, we don't define it here
    delimiter = f'"{hour}","postCount":"'
    # now we use a generic name inside the function.
    result = df.copy()
    result['hour'] = hour
    result['totalCount']=df.post_time_data.str.split(delimiter).str[1].str.split('","topic').str[0]
    # At the last step of the original process, we `return` the value
    # instead of simply assigning it.
    return result.fillna(0)
```

Now we have code that, given an `'hour'` string, can produce a new dataframe, simply by calling it - for example: `df_h0 = hourly_data(df, '00:00')`.

## Step 5: A bit more analysis.

We would like to call this function with each possible hour value, presumably from `'00:00'` through `'23:00'` inclusive. However, these strings have an obvious pattern to them. It would be easier if we just supply the *number* for the hour to `hourly_data`, and have it produce the string.

```
def hourly_data(df, hour):
    # Locally replace the integer hour value with the hour string.
    # The `:02` here is used to zero-pad and right-align the hour value
    # as two digits.
    hour = f'{hour:02}:00'
    delimiter = f'"{hour}","postCount":"'
    # The rest as before.
    result = df.copy()
    result['hour'] = hour
    result['totalCount']=df.post_time_data.str.split(delimiter).str[1].str.split('","topic').str[0]
    return result.fillna(0)
```

## Step 6: Now we are ready to use this code in a loop.

In Python, the natural loop to "transform" one input list into another is the *list comprehension*. It looks like this:

```
hourly_dfs = [hourly_data(df, hour) for hour in range(24)]
```

Here, [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is a built-in function that gives us the desired sequence of input values.

We can also build the list manually with a `for` loop:

```
hourly_dfs = []
for hour in range(24):
    hourly_dfs.append(hourly_data(df, hour))
```

We could also have done the work inside the body of the `for` loop (someone else will probably come along with another answer and show code like that). But by making the function first, we get code that is easier to understand, and which also allows us to use a list comprehension. The list comprehension approach is simpler, because we don't have to think about the process of starting from empty and `.append`ing each element, we let Python build a list instead of telling it how to do so.

Answer (score -1):

You could make a list of the variables and iterate over them and use the `string.format` method

```
vars = [df_h0, df_h1, df_h2] 
x = 0

for var in vars:
  var = df.copy()
  var['hour']='0{0}:00'.format(x)
  var['totalCount']=df.post_time_data.str.split('0{0}:00", "postCount":'. format(x)).str[1].str.split('","topic').str[0]
  var = var.fillna(0)
  x += 1
```

If you have Python 3.6+ you can use `f strings` instead of `.format()` as well

Hopefully I havent missed anything, but if I have, you could just impletent the same logic I used by declaring anither variable like `x`